# Magento 2.1 - Emails not being sent - Shared cPanel Hosting

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, transactional-mail

I have everything set up correctly with the below cronjobs running fine but I'm not receiving order confirmation emails?

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -c /opt/alt/php7/etc/php.ini  /home/username/public_html/magento_root/bin/magento cron:run >> /home/username/public_html/magento_root/var/log/magento.cron.log&

*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -c /opt/alt/php7/etc/php.ini  /home/username/public_html/magento_root/update/cron.php >> /home/username/public_html/magento_root/var/log/update.cron.log&

*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -c /opt/alt/php7/etc/php.ini /home/username/public_html/magento_root/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/username/public_html/magento_root/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

All of the logs show these are running correctly.

Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: is other emails working - like register, contact us , forget pw ? did you checked email is set in backend configuration, check in spam too....

Comment: I forgot to set the emails in admin, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the **email id** in admin